# passing data to the styles component angular2

Tags: css, angular

How can I pass data from angular tag to the styles in the `@Component`?

**Here is my component:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'icon',
  template: `<svg class="icon"><use attr.xlink:href="#{{name}}"></use></svg>`,
  styles: ['.icon{width:{{size}}px;}'] 
})
export class IconComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() size: any; 

  constructor() { }

}
```

I wanna set size property from component.

**used in html file:**

```
<icon name="logo" size="37"></icon>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding in styles is not supported. You can use style binding like

```
template: `<svg class="icon" [style.width.px]="size"><use attr.xlink:href="#{{name}}"></use></svg>`,
```

Comment: can't we pass value from component to styles.scss?

Comment: Not in a straight-forward way. https://medium.com/@amcdnl/theming-angular-with-css-variables-3c78a5b20b24 might give some inspiration or the other answer from rivanov. Mine is a bit old and outdated already.

Comment: Perhaps better to create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually surprised that I finally found a somewhat solid solution to this using a [ngx-css-variables](https://github.com/lironbob/ngx-css-variables).

My use case is that I have a 3rd-party library, which creates many child components within itself, as it draws charts.

I needed to set the linear gradient with a `url(#<uuid>)`.

**CSS Template**

```
  /deep/ngx-charts-line-chart {
  display: flex;
  /deep/ngx-charts-chart {
    display: flex;
    div.ngx-charts-outer {
      display: flex;
      svg {
        .line {
          stroke: var(--gradient);
          stroke-width: 4px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
import * as uuid from 'uuid/v4';
...
  private _linearGradientId = uuid();
  get uuid() {
    return this._linearGradientId;
  }
  get gradientCss() {
    return {
      '--gradient': `url(#${this.uuid})`
    }
  }
...
```

**HTML Template**

```
...
<ngx-charts-line-chart
  [css-vars]="gradientCss"
...
<ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

You still have to deep style the component since it's components are not in your template, but `ngx-css-variables` will inject a function into the `style` property, which seems hacky, but it works!

So now the `stroke` comes from that dynamic function at runtime. Super cool. I wish angular supported this natively.